# Frankenstein shortened to Frank

Tags: frankensteins-monster

Has anyone ever called Frankenstein Frank before in any movies, books or other media? Or has Frankenstein just been called Frankenstein?

Comment: To be clear, are you referring to Dr Frankenstein, who would probably never be called “Frank,” or to his monster (whom I believe no less a luminary than Bugs Bunny has calked “Frankie?”)

Comment: There was the 1976 Saturday morning show [Monster Squad](https://imdb.com/title/tt0128000/) with a character named Frank N. Stein. Trust me, you didn't miss much.

Comment: And Frank N Furter is based on Frankenstein, obviously.

Comment: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Dr._Devil_and_Mr._Hare

Answer (score 2):

I can't trivially prove that Bugs Bunny has called Frankenstein's Monster "Frankie" (as alluded to in a comment by [James McLeod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4804); however, I can prove that another character with a similar sense of humor has:

[image: Spider-Man calls Frankenstein's Monster "Frankie" in a death trap]

In the early to mid 1970s, Marvel Comics published *The Monster Of Frankenstein*. And, as they also published *Marvel Team-Up*, they had Spider-Man meeting all sorts of characters (some licensed, some public domain) also being published by them at the time. Spider-Man had met the likes of Dracula, Fu Manchu (and his son, Shang-Chi), Doc Savage - and, inevitably, the Monster.

Spider-Man met him and teamed up with him in *Marvel Team-Up* # 36-37 (cover-dated August and September 1975 respectively, with a Spider-Man-related werewolf character named Man-Wolf being the "official" team-up character for # 37).

The only surprising thing here is it taking until page 6 of the *second* comic for Spider-Man to actually call him "Frankie"!

Answer (score 0):

In the "Hotel Transylvania" animated series, Frankenstein's monster goes by "Frank".